# Visual Studio 2015 freezes when debugging a cpp code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I'm trying to create a c++ OpenGL project, however, it always freezes when I'm debugging(ctrl + f5). I've tried to write a simple program that prints text to the screen and it still freezes. The build completes successfully, projects in C# don't freeze as well. When I'm trying to run the cpp project VS freezes completely and I have to kill the process, running the .exe directly freezes the explorer..
I haven't found any solution to that kind of problem in the web, and I was hoping that someone here will know what to do..

Thanks :)

Comment: *I'm trying to create a c++ OpenGL project*  -- then you say -- *I've tried to write a simple program that prints text to the screen*.  What is the "simple program"?  Is it a simple "Hello World" without any OpenGL?

Comment: Yeah, a simple hello world program.

Comment: Do you have include directives? Did you alter the project settings? Did you try a clean build? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you. Turns out my Avast anti-virus was causing the issue. I disabled it and now it's working.

I found the answer from this question:
[Visual Studio 2015 freezes when finished building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675368/visual-studio-2015-freezes-when-finished-building)

Comment: Yes, apparently the anti-virus blocked my VS.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a breakpoint on the very first line of your main, click on debug and see if it gets to the breakpoint. If it does, try stepping through until you see what is causing your freeze.

Comment: It doesn't work, the debugger freezes before anything happens, and the main contains only one cout command and a return 0...

Comment: How about the Output Window when you debug?  What does it say?  Are there DLL's loaded?  If so, which one was the last one loaded?