# Visual Studio 2015 freezes when finished building

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2015, freeze

My copy of Visual Studio 2015 Community freezes/becomes unresponsive when it's trying to run a successful build, everything else operates as normal. If a build fails, VS operates as it should, giving me an output prompt.

Only when the Output states that the build's been successful, the IDE freezes with no response and even running the compiled .exe from the Debug folder freezes Win Explorer. All projects have been either C++ or C#.

OS: Windows 10, 
IDE's/Suites installed: VS2015 and Unity 5.2.1f1

Answer (score 5):

2 options:

- are there any post-build events in your project?
- disable the antivirus

Comment: Thank you! It's just a 3D render, no post-build events.  Disabled Avast and VS outputs a working build fine, Avast never blocked events like this before, is there anyway to whitelist VS builds?

Comment: If you have something similar to d:\projects you can whitelist it, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I was experiencing the same behavior in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Enterprise (build started but then froze) with McAfee antivirus - I had to completely uninstall it to get building in VS working.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem here. Building takes forever and I had to stop it manually. 

I went to the project folder and I gives it write permissions and now its working fine. Such an easy thing that took me 3 days to realize!

Comment: We use Webroot SecureAnywhere at work and it was contributing to a similar delay. Definitely check your anti-virus solution.

Answer (score 4):

VS 2015 was hanging about half of the time when I would build a particular solution containing seven projects (four C# and one C++).

Under Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run, I changed the
Maximum number of parallel project builds from 4 to 1.

This appears to have eliminated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like running Visual Studio as Administrator solved the problem for me. (For always running a program as Administrator see [How to Run Visual Studio as Administrator by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default))